# Breakpoints stopped working in Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

All of a sudden breakpoints in Visual C++ have stopped breaking. I'm building the project in Debug mode. During execution the breakpoints say put as red dots, not as hollow dots (which would mean that it won't break due to lack of some debugging information) but still it doesn't break.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 Enterprise Edition.

Please help before I shoot myself.

Comment: Maybe, that portion of code isn't being executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with IE 8. It started breaking at breakpoints after I downgraded to IE 6. Cruel microsoft developers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the code in question is supposed to run at all?

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the program, the Breakpoints will always show as RED solid dots.

If the debug symbols aren't correct, then those red dots will become hollow only at runtime.

Try cleaning the project and build it again.

One possibility might be that your code isn't compiling after the latest changes, and your older symbol & binaries aren't matching your new code.

Thats why cleaning and rebuilding might solve that issue.

Comment: I have cleaned the project and rebuilt it. I'm also talking about solid red dots at runtime only.

Comment: okay, this will help you: Call [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx) in the beginning of your code. You might need to include <windows.h>.

Comment: @hugh if it breaks at the line of DebugBreak(), then you are good to go; but if it doesn't break, then that means execution isn't reaching that part of the code.

Comment: It doesn't break at DebugBreak() either. But I know it is running through that portion because I've written some log messages which are getting written everytime.

Comment: Try [this solution to another similar problem on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044103/debugbreak-not-breaking/1044296#1044296). And [same thing with some screenshots](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2009/06/what-to-do-when-debugbreak-wont-let-me.html). Let me know how it goes. But if it doesn't work, just please don't shoot yourself (instead ask again on SO).

Answer (score 0):

It happens when after u building u made some change to the source code. Put ur pointer to that hollow dot it will give that message.

Make sure you have all the included files in same condition when u build the solution

Comment: I don't get hollow dot. It remains solid as though it is going to break, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This happens from time to time, restarting Visual Studio seems to cure it.

Comment: No, I have restarted 10^9 times.

Comment: Try to kill the background process "msvssrv" (if I remember the name correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Does the code that you are trying to break into exist in a separate dll or plugin? - I have found from time to time that my breakpoints are disabled if the dll that the code is in has failed to load for some reason, so if it is in a dll - ensure the dll is being loaded correctly by putting a break in DllMain.

Comment: It is not a separate dll. It is the same dll that I'm launching from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this many times. Try toggling your build (solution configuration) between release and debug (cleaning and rebuilding on both). That should fix it. At least, it does for me every time. Hope that helps brother.